# How can I make a button keep the focused css style till I click on it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want the button to stay with the hover css style regardless of every other activity instead of going back to the normal style. Please help out!

```js
$(function() {
      var clickCount = 0;
      $('.menu').click(function() {
            if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
              //do when open
              $('#css-menu').css({right: '0'});
        }else{
             //do when closed
             $('css-menu').css({right: '-340px'});
         }
        clickCount++;
    });
});
```

```css
.main-nav ul li.menu {
} 
.main-nav ul li.menu:after {
} 
.main-nav ul li.menu:hover:after {
}
```

```html
<li class='menu' title='Menu'></li>
```

Comment: What about instead of  creating a :hover css style, you add a "hover" class to your element when it is clicked. In your CSS, you should then 
.main-nav ul li.menu .hover {
}

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to work at all, but the pattern @r4phG describes should solve your issue

Comment: What @r4phG said plus instead of using a counter value to determine which action to take (open or close the menu) you could check the menu's class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses Jquery to manually add and remove a class from a button witch the CSS then picks up. Is this what you wanted?

html

```
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()"> select </button>
```

js

```
function myFunction() {
   if($( "#button" ).hasClass( "hover" )){
      $( "#button" ).removeClass( "hover" )
   }
   else{
      $( "#button" ).addClass( "hover" );
   }
}
```

css

```
.hover{
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
```

}

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentionned in the comments, you should work with classes instead of a counter and the :hover selector. Here is what I think you should do :

```
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("hover")) {
         $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }else{
         $(this).addClass("hover");
     }
});
```

Then in your CSS, create a style with .menu .hover :

```
.main-nav ul li.menu .hover {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stay hovered color using `CSS` then you need to use `:visited` `:visited` is a pseudo-class selector that can change some of the styling on an anchor link`(a)`. So you can't use for `li`.

but you can use like this `.main-nav ul li.menu a {}` and `.main-nav ul li.menu a:hover, .main-nav ul li.menu a:visited, .main-nav ul li.menu a:active {}`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1utc1o8/11/